# Free Space in DropdownList

Tags: c#

Inserting Data Into Drop Down List Based on two or more Conditions.An Extra Space is Display Bellow all Items in Drop down list Which is not consider an item Because of Validation Working.
How to remove the free Space.
The code is Given Bellow:-

```
private void loadUserGroup()
{
    CUsers objCUsers=new CUsers();
    ddlUserGroup.Items.Clear();
    ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));
    ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Admin", "2"));
    string suseid= User.Identity.Name;
    int iUserID = Convert.ToInt32(suseid.ToString());
    long iUserParent = objCUsers.SelectUserParent(iUserID);

    int iadID=objCUsers.SelectUserIDforAdmin(ddlUserGroup.Items[0].Text);
    if(iUserParent==0 || iUserParent==null)
    {
        ddlUserGroup.Visible = false;
        lblUserGroup.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (iUserParent == iadID)
    {
        ddlUserGroup.Visible = true;
        lblUserGroup.Visible = true;
        ddlUserGroup.Items.RemoveAt(0);

        ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Dealer", "4"));
        ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Admin", "3"));//Similar To Admin
    }
    else
    {
        long iUserGroup = objCUsers.SelectUserGroup(iUserID);
        if(iUserGroup==4)
        {
            ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Company", "5"));       
        }
        else if(iUserGroup==3)
        {
            ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Admin", "3"));
        }
        else if (iUserGroup == 5)
        {          
            ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Company", "5"));
        }       
    }   
}
```

Comment: Uhm, if you debugged and stepped-through your code you'd see where you're adding empty items to the list. Why didn't you do that first?

Comment: ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0")); is the empty item

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the following line:

```
ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0")); // blank line
```

So the new code looks like:

```
private void loadUserGroup()
{
    CUsers objCUsers=new CUsers();
    ddlUserGroup.Items.Clear();
    //ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "0"));
    ddlUserGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Admin", "2"));
    string suseid= User.Identity.Name;
    int iUserID = Convert.ToInt32(suseid.ToString());
```